# What is the recommended approach to use ancient VCL components?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I am an experienced programmer, but quite new to C++ Builder, so here are a couple of newbie questions :

I'm currently refreshing an old codebase that is compiled with BCB5. My aim is to use the XE version in the end, but since there is so much work (huge codebase) I'm making a first stop at the BCB6 station (mostly because I can keep using the same STL version with the _USE_OLD_RW_STL preprocessor define).

I have the source for most of the third party VCL components used, except 2, for which I only have the foo.bpi/foo.bpl couple + headers. The direct consequence is that those still require vcl50.bpl to link/run.

1. Is there a way to disassemble/reassemble the foo.bpl file so it can link/run with a more recent VCL lib ?
2. On the other hand, is it OK to include vcl50.bpl in the final product package along with a more recent vcl.bpl file, just to be used by those 2 components ?
3. Any better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly? I'd try to find an up-to-date replacement for these components. What kind of components are these?

Comment: They are custom-made components for whom the company seems to have lost the sources (or a contractor may have "forgotten" to provide them, I don't really know and the history is of course lost).The point is that I will only be able to use the binary form.

Comment: Responding to myself : 2. seems out of question, there is some kind of runtime mechanism presumably triggered when trying to load a package, that throws an exception complaining that a unit (AppEvnts) is implemented in both packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VCL packages are version-specific.  You cannot use BCB5 packages in an XE project.  You must obtain XE-specific versions of those components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain the technical details leading to this limitation ? Since I won't be able to obtain newer versions I need to be absolutely sure that nothing can be done before throwing the towel.

Comment: @cdelacroix: Remy is right, nothing can be done.  The internal format of objects can change between versions, for example, as can RTL details. When you upgrade to XE, you will find `TObject`s have a different size, `String`s are different, etc... you won't be able to install the BPL into the IDE. You do need the source to recompile, or instead find a replacement component, as Remy says.  You could post about the components with a screenshot or two and ask for alternatives here on SO! There are a lot out there, and someone may be able to point you to one or give tips on writing a replacement.